# lldb on Mac Qt C++

Tags: c++, macos, qt, lldb

I am trying to use LLDB to debug a Qt C++ program. I have never used LLDB before. First problem I am having is that it does not show the C++ code I am on - only the offset from the BP and the assembly code, e.g.:

```
(lldb) n
Process 29690 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x270041, 0x0000000100066cfe foo`workItem::packageDataAndTransitionToReport() + 30, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = instruction step over
    frame #0: 0x0000000100066cfe foo`workItem::packageDataAndTransitionToReport() + 30
foo`workItem::packageDataAndTransitionToReport() + 30:
-> 0x100066cfe:  movq   %rcx, -0x48(%rbp)
   0x100066d02:  movq   -0x40(%rbp), %rdx
   0x100066d06:  movq   %rdx, -0x30(%rbp)
   0x100066d0a:  movq   %rcx, -0x38(%rbp)
```

How can I get it to show the C++ line it's stopped at and not the assembly code?

Second problem is, how do I list out the source code. The familiar l command from gdb does not work, it produces no output.

Comment: did you compile with `-g`. use this table for finding equivalent lldb commands http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html

Comment: Thanks. That was it.

Comment: Oh great I will put it as answer. Please accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-g` flag while compiling.

Use this link to find the corresponding lldb commands http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html